# XAML mouse cursor converter not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to change the mouse cursor of a XAML control using a converter.

First check:

```
<Border Cursor="Help">
```

This does work fine, I get the help cursor when mouse is over the control.

Now if I implement the converter this way:

```
 public class MouseCursorConverter : IValueConverter
    {


        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {

               if(<my logic>)
                       return System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Help;
               else
                       return System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
                }

            }
            catch
            {

                return null;
            }
        }
...
}
```

and then call it this way:

```
 <Border  Cursor="{Binding pointCapture, Converter={StaticResource MouseCursorConverter}}">
```

I can see that the converter is called when needed and it does return the correct value.
But the value is ignored when I mouse-over the control.

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you mean that if you over the border your binding pointCapture is modified ? I wonder how the binding can work in the way you want.

Comment: My first idea would be to add a behavior to handle a such thing

Comment: The other way around, when I modify pointCapture, it raises an event.
Then the view attempts to redraw the control, invokes  the converter  that returns the expected value.
But still the mouse cursor stayed unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the WinForms cursors, try [System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.cursor(v=vs.110).aspx).

It works in XAML thanks to the TypeConverter.